# Get all the values with same class name in selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, web-crawler

I want to get the article names and url of articles with the same class name.
Issue is, it prints just one information again and again instead of all the artilces.

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\muhammad.usman\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.aljazeera.com/news/')
# to get the current location ...
driver.current_url
button = driver.find_element_by_id('btn_showmore_b1_418')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)
content = driver.find_element_by_class_name('topics-sec-block')
print(content)
container = content.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="col-sm-7 topics-sec-item-cont"]')
print(container)
i=0
for i in range(0, 12):
    title = []
    url = []
    heading=container[i].find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="col-sm-7 topics-sec-item-cont"]/a/h2').text
    link = container[i].find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="col-sm-7 topics-sec-item-cont"]/a')
    title.append(heading)
    url.append(link.get_attribute('href'))
    print(title)
    print(url)
    i += 1
names = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.topics-sec-item-cont')
for name in names:

    heading=name.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="col-sm-7 topics-sec-item-cont"]/a/h2').text
    link = name.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="col-sm-7 topics-sec-item-cont"]/a')
    print(heading)
    print(link.get_attribute('href'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Exclusively using Selenium**

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.aljazeera.com/news/')
# to get the current location ...
driver.current_url
button = driver.find_element_by_id('btn_showmore_b1_418')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)
content = driver.find_element_by_class_name('topics-sec-block')
print(content)

div_nodes = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.topics-sec-item-cont")

titleList = []
urlList = []
for div in div_nodes:
    w=1
    heading=div.find_element_by_tag_name('h2').text
    link = div.find_element_by_tag_name('a').get_attribute('href')
    titleList.append(heading)
    urlList.append(link)
    print('HEADLINE: %s\nUrl: https://www.aljazeera.com%s\n' %(heading, link) + '-'*70 + '\n' )

driver.close()
```

**Output:**

```
HEADLINE: Georgia priests bless Tbilisi city in bid to contain COVID-19
Url: https://www.aljazeera.comhttps://www.aljazeera.com/topics/country/georgia.html
----------------------------------------------------------------------

HEADLINE: India's banking crisis: Government rescues fourth-largest bank
Url: https://www.aljazeera.comhttps://www.aljazeera.com/ajimpact
----------------------------------------------------------------------

HEADLINE: Art world's 'cold case': Heist of the century still intrigues
Url: https://www.aljazeera.comhttps://www.aljazeera.com/topics/subjects/art.html
----------------------------------------------------------------------

HEADLINE: Italy's coronavirus death toll surges past 2,500 - Live updates
Url: https://www.aljazeera.comhttps://www.aljazeera.com/topics/events/coronavirus-outbreak.html
----------------------------------------------------------------------

HEADLINE: Coronavirus: All you need to know in 500 words
Url: https://www.aljazeera.comhttps://www.aljazeera.com/topics/categories/health.html
----------------------------------------------------------------------

HEADLINE: Timeline: How the new coronavirus spread
Url: https://www.aljazeera.comhttps://www.aljazeera.com/topics/events/coronavirus-outbreak.html
----------------------------------------------------------------------

HEADLINE: How long does coronavirus last on surfaces and in air?
Url: https://www.aljazeera.comhttps://www.aljazeera.com/topics/events/coronavirus-outbreak.html
----------------------------------------------------------------------

HEADLINE: India's poor testing rate may have masked coronavirus cases
Url: https://www.aljazeera.comhttps://www.aljazeera.com/topics/events/coronavirus-outbreak.html
----------------------------------------------------------------------

HEADLINE: Turkey announces first coronavirus death amid jump in cases
Url: https://www.aljazeera.comhttps://www.aljazeera.com/topics/country/turkey.html
----------------------------------------------------------------------

HEADLINE: Footballer Obi Mikel quits Turkish club over coronavirus fears
Url: https://www.aljazeera.comhttps://www.aljazeera.com/topics/categories/sport.html
----------------------------------------------------------------------

HEADLINE: Pakistan PM: 'Cannot afford' to shut down cities over coronavirus
Url: https://www.aljazeera.comhttps://www.aljazeera.com/topics/events/coronavirus-outbreak.html
----------------------------------------------------------------------

HEADLINE: Tension, fear as South Africa steps up coronavirus fight
Url: https://www.aljazeera.comhttps://www.aljazeera.com/topics/categories/health.html
----------------------------------------------------------------------

HEADLINE: China to expel more US journalists in escalating row over media
Url: https://www.aljazeera.comhttps://www.aljazeera.com/topics/country/china.html
----------------------------------------------------------------------

HEADLINE: High treatment costs stop Americans from testing for coronavirus
Url: https://www.aljazeera.comhttps://www.aljazeera.com/topics/events/coronavirus-outbreak.html
----------------------------------------------------------------------

HEADLINE: Saudi Arabia urges G20 virtual talk on coronavirus, shuts mosques
Url: https://www.aljazeera.comhttps://www.aljazeera.com/topics/events/coronavirus-outbreak.html
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 2):

**Using Selenium and BeautifulSoup**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.aljazeera.com/news/')
# to get the current location ...
driver.current_url
button = driver.find_element_by_id('btn_showmore_b1_418')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)
content = driver.find_element_by_class_name('topics-sec-block')
print(content)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
container = soup.select('div.topics-sec-item-cont')

titleList = []
urlList = []
for item in container:
    heading=item.find('h2').text
    link = item.find('a')['href']
    titleList.append(heading)
    urlList.append(link)
    print('HEADLINE: %s\nUrl: https://www.aljazeera.com%s\n' %(heading, link) + '-'*70 + '\n' )



driver.close()
```

**Output:**

```
HEADLINE: Trump's Remain in Mexico policy endangers migrants headed to US
Url: https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2020/03/trumps-remain-mexico-policy-endangers-migrants-headed-200306102155930.html
----------------------------------------------------------------------

HEADLINE: India, South Korea report new coronavirus cases: Live updates
Url: https://www.aljazeera.com/topics/events/coronavirus-outbreak.html
----------------------------------------------------------------------

HEADLINE: Clashes between Greek police, migrants reported on Turkish border
Url: https://www.aljazeera.com/topics/subjects/refugees.html
----------------------------------------------------------------------

HEADLINE: Congo protests against unpaid pensions as gov't debt balloons
Url: https://www.aljazeera.com/topics/regions/africa.html
----------------------------------------------------------------------

HEADLINE: Is India prepared for coronavirus outbreak?
Url: https://www.aljazeera.com/topics/events/coronavirus-outbreak.html
----------------------------------------------------------------------

HEADLINE: India protest violence leaves thousands displaced
Url: https://www.aljazeera.com/topics/regions/asia.html
----------------------------------------------------------------------

HEADLINE: Guinea protests: One dead in anti-government demonstration
Url: https://www.aljazeera.com/topics/regions/africa.html
----------------------------------------------------------------------

HEADLINE: Brazil recalls diplomats, officials from Venezuela
Url: https://www.aljazeera.com/topics/country/brazil.html
----------------------------------------------------------------------

HEADLINE: US coronavirus: rise in cases in New York state
Url: https://www.aljazeera.com/topics/events/coronavirus-outbreak.html
----------------------------------------------------------------------

HEADLINE: Australia urged to take action amid rising violence against women
Url: https://www.aljazeera.com/topics/country/australia.html
----------------------------------------------------------------------

HEADLINE: Turkey, Russia announce ceasefire in Syria's Idlib
Url: https://www.aljazeera.com/topics/regions/middleeast.html
----------------------------------------------------------------------

HEADLINE: 'Good morning, Codogno!': A coronavirus radio station in Italy
Url: https://www.aljazeera.com/topics/country/italy.html
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I want to solve it using selenium, If anyone can help.

Comment: @Usmankhan I added the solution exclusively using selenium. Please accept that solution.